# Replicate Multiple Interfaces into a Generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a basic structure which I've created multiple similar interfaces:

```
interface Time {
    command: 'time';
    data: number;
}

interface Print {
    command: 'print';
    data: string;
}

type Command = Time | Print;
```

I want to replicate this behavior but instead of having to manually create multiple interfaces it should automatically match the data to the required function arguments. The example below doesn't work as it's mixing the arguments of both functions, saying it could be either number or string for both commands.

```
type Commands = keyof typeof commands;

interface Command<T extends Commands> {
    command: T;
    data: Parameters<typeof commands[T]>[0];
}

let SERVER_TIME = 0;

const commands = {
    time: (time: number) => (SERVER_TIME = time),
    print: (msg: string) => console.log(msg),
} as const;

function processCommand<T extends Command<Commands>>(command: T['command'], data: T['data']) {
    if (!(command in commands)) {
        console.warn(`Unknown command received from server: ${command} - ${data}`);
        return;
    }
    return commands[command](data); // Error*
}

processCommand('print',2); // No error shown! Should show an error
```

> Error: Argument of type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

It's not matching the command and I can't figure out why. Does anyone understands what I am doing wrong? And thank you in advance!

Comment: "typescript-typings" is not an appropriate tag for this question.  What are `SERVER_TIME` and `log`?  If they are not vital to your question could you remove them and replace them with something suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?

Comment: "The example below doesn't work as it's mixing the arguments of both functions, saying it could be either number or string for both commands." Could you provide the error message that goes along with this? Anyway this looks like it's probably another instance of [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and surprisingly similar to [this q/a I just did](//stackoverflow.com/q/73858593/2887218) where the solution looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLyDAW). Does that address the question fully? If so I could write an answer (or close as duplicate). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The InputMap worked like a charm! Thank you!